# Parse a string into multiple arguments

Tags: c

I need to program a multiplayer game. The server can receive multiple messages from the client. Each message has multiple / no arguments.

Some examples of messages I can receive (there are many more) :

```
JOING Player1 8080 5*** // Client joins game 5, client port is 8080, client name is "Player 1".
CREAT Player1 5050*** // Client with name: "Player1" and port: 5050 creates a game.
LEAVE*** // Client leaves the current game.
```

Every message operation (JOING, CREAT, LEAVE) is 5 characters long. Every message ends with ***.

Some operations have arguments, some don't.

Some operations have multiple arguments.

Of course, I know the exact size of each argument. Ex port is 4 chars, game id (5 in first example) is exactly one byte.

I want to write a function `parse(char *str)` that parses the string, whatever the operation is, and returns the operation id (I created unique int operations id's), and the potential arguments.

I have around 20 operations I need to handle. I could write a struct for each operation, and return the struct.

I feel that this method is not very smart.

Is there a way to do better ?

Thank you

Comment: You will have to create a struct for your operations anyway. How else would you handle the parsed result in your code?

Comment: Let's go creating 20+ structs haha, btw well yes, depending on the way I store the data, the parser will do different things. That's why I asked both.

Comment: You can have single structure, with a member that stores array of pointers to arguments (if any). Based on opcode you can access indexed tokens.

Comment: Oh that's a good idea @SparKot. Do you think it's possible to implement a general parser, that works for every operation and builds the struct ?

Comment: @0xRyN Yes, it is. Define a struct that holds your command and arguments. Then define a parse function that splits your command string into tokens (i.e. the command and its arguments).

Comment: Yes, just like `argc` & `argv` for `main()`. `struct command {
int opcode;
char* cmd;  /* base address to free later */
int argc;   /* count of args parsed */
char** args; /* chopped up cmd */
/*
... other members
*/
}`

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. I just don't get why `char* cmd` is in the struct. (since we have OPCODE)

Comment: I get the impression, you consider 20+ struct types to be a large number. Well, it's not. Do whatever makes your code easier to write, better to read and better to maintain. Being lazy is the worst idea during programming.

Comment: @Gerhardh Yeah I was just being lazy about the 20+ structs. And the giant switch cases to fill every specific struct depending on operation. What do you think about the other answer ? Would it be a nightmare to write and maintain ?

Comment: Having `argc` and `argv` in the struct does not sound like parsing the strings. It is just splitting the strings and let the work do the function handling the command. You can do that. It has pro's and con's.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, define the struct you are going to be using:

```c
enum Command {JOING, CREAT, LEAVE /*, ...*/};

struct command {
    enum Command com;
    char *args[10]; // Or whataver your maximum number of arguments is
    int nargs;
};
```

Then, define a split function:

```c
bool split(const char *str, const char sep, char **tokens, const int maxtokens, int *ntokens)
{
    *ntokens = 0;
    const char *start = str;
    for (const char *p = str; /*no condition*/; ++p) {
        if (*p == sep || *p == '\0') {
            if (*ntokens >= maxtokens)
                return false;
            
            int len = p - start;
            char *tmp = malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 1));
            strncpy(tmp, start, len);
            tokens[(*ntokens)++] = tmp;
            
            if (!*p)
                return true;
            
            start = p + 1;
        }
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

You can use it like:

```c
struct command parse(const char *str)
{
    struct command cmd;
    split(str, ' ', cmd.args, 10, &cmd.nargs);

    if (!strcmp(cmd.args[0], "JOING"))
        cmd.com = JOING;
    else if (!strcmp(cmd.args[0], "CREAT"))
        cmd.com = CREAT;
    /*...*/
    
    return cmd;
}
```